# Нарисовать граф

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, graph

Нужна помощь в отрисовке графа. 
Может быть любое количество элементов с разным весом. В зависимости от веса меняется размер элемента. Также нужно определять главный элемент. 
В идеале внутри элементов должна быть возможность добавлять картинки.

Я пробовала юзать [vis.js](http://visjs.org), но он вроде не особо гибкий для реализаиции такого графа. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский, либо задайте его на [english SO](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/969307/188366

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте применить библиотеку d3.js https://d3js.org/
Как пример https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

Comment: Хм.. Желательно бы скопировать пример в ответ...