# Отрисовка графов

Tags: javascript, php, html, svg

Хочу задать параметры для графа в на web-странице, обработать их и отрисовать граф, за тем сформировать массив с данными(какая вершина с какой соединена и параметры например длинна соединительной линии) и перегнать например массив в текстовый файл и отправить в программу на с++ (уже написана) какой инструмент(библиотека) лучше всего подходит именно для отрисовки графа? P.S. с JS не особо знаком

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: слишком абстрактно, приведите пример картинкой или как то еще

Comment: https://yandex.ru/images/search?pos=0&img_url=http%3A%2F%2Fjs-tutorial.com%2Fupload%2Fimages%2Fchart%2Fsigmajs%2Fsigmajs-1.jpg&text=sigma%20js&rpt=simage  к примеру вот картинка изображения графа. Соответственно нужно что-то такое

Comment: если к примеру перейти по вашей ссылке и то будет написано sigma.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Есть удачная во всех отношениях библиотека d3.js, в ней есть так называемый force layout, вот я собрал простенький пример использования.

Граф нарисован при помощи `svg` элементов `<circle>` и `<line>`, цвет круга зависит от группы узла, цвет и штриховка линий зависят от значения "силы" связи между узлами

UPD: подкрутил алгоритм генерации рандомного графа

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let graph = {
  groups: Array(11).fill(0).map(() => rnd(10)).map((d,i) => Array(11).fill(0).map(()=>({
    id: Math.random().toString(36).substring(2), 
    group: i
  }))),
  links: []
};

graph.nodes = graph.groups.reduce((acc, arr) => acc.concat(arr), []);

graph.superNode = graph.nodes[rnd(graph.nodes.length)].id;

graph.groups.forEach(nodes => {

  nodes.forEach(n => {
  
    for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {
      let n2 = nodes[rnd(nodes.length)];
      graph.links.push({
        source: n.id, 
        target: n2.id, 
        value: rnd(10)
      });
      checkLastLink(n, n2);
    }
    
  });

  for (var i=0;i<2;i++){
    let node = nodes[rnd(nodes.length)];
    let node2 =  graph.groups[rnd(graph.groups.length)][0];
    graph.links.push({
      source: node.id, 
      target:node2.id, 
      value: rnd(2)
    });
    checkLastLink(node, node2);
  }
  

})


function checkLastLink(src, target) {
  if (!src.highlight) {
    src.highlight = target.id === graph.superNode;
  }
  
  if (!target.highlight) {
    target.highlight = src.id === graph.superNode;
  }
}

console.log(graph)

// код выше нужен чтобы сгененрировать данные 

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(d => d.id))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-4))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

var link = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("stroke", 'red')
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", d => (1+d.value*2) + ' ' + 3);

var node = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", d => d.id===graph.superNode ? 15: d.highlight?6:3)
      .attr("fill", d => color(d.group))
      .attr("stroke", 'black')
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

  simulation.nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

function ticked() {
  link.attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
      .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
      .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
      .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);

  node.attr("cx", d => d.x)
      .attr("cy", d => d.y);
}

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) 
    simulation.alphaTarget(1).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) 
    simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

function rnd(base){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * base);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="700" height="500"></svg>
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, все, что для такой цели может быть использовано основано на JS? И без него здесь не обойтись?

Comment: @Валерий ну Вы спросили про javascript...

Comment: Можно задать еще один вопрос?

Comment: @Валерий а почему бы и нет