# Как сверстать граф?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, d3.js

Есть вот такой дизайн:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Его нужно сверстать, и сделать анимацию подобную этой arborjs.org

Данная библиотека на мобильных устройствах не корректно работает. Да и для стилизации не подходит. И получается не совсем то, что нужно в работе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как или через что это можно реализовать?

Comment: Сейчас пробую использовать вот это https://bl.ocks.org/heybignick/3faf257bbbbc7743bb72310d03b86ee8

Не могу найти как увеличить длину линий между элементами http://prntscr.com/ocxgfm. 

Шрифт увеличил через css http://prntscr.com/ocxg03, расстояние между элементами не могу найти параметра.

Comment: посмотрите этот мой ответ, может быть он Вам поможет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/969307/188366, длина связи то параметр `value` у `link`

Comment: спасибо, а как заменить random, на получение данных из файла json?

Comment: это уже достойно полноценного ответа, если приведете пример данных, я вечерком сделаю пример кода, ну и Ваш код можно тоже, чтобы было ближе к делу.

Comment: вот в таком формате данные, либо прям в js вносить эти данные http://prntscr.com/oczvqy

Comment: код взял с примера по ссылке

Comment: вашего прошлого ответа

Comment: это главное направление: http://prntscr.com/oczxho
это направления, которые выходят из главного http://prntscr.com/oczwpe
а из каждого направления, есть под направления http://prntscr.com/oczxam

Comment: вот еще https://stackoverflow.com/a/55680108/2393786

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: Stranger in the Q написал, что сегодня вечером покажет пример реализации данного примера, позже я обновлю вопрос в более верный для базы знаний.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот пример графа на `d3` и `forceLayout`, который инициализируется из простого объекта с данными, с произвольной стилизацией узлов:

```js
let bigCircle = "M-100,0a100,100,0,1,1,0,0.001z";
let smallCircle = "M-50,0a50,50,0,1,1,0,0.001z";
let rect = "m-50 -25 h100 v50 h-100z";

let graph = {
  nodes: [
  {id:1, shape:bigCircle, color:'red'},
  {id:11, shape:smallCircle, color:'lightgray'}, 
  {id:12, shape:smallCircle, color:'lightgray'},
  {id:13, shape:smallCircle, color:'lightgray'},
  {id:111}, {id:112},{id:113},
  {id:121}, {id:122},{id:123},
  {id:131}, {id:132},{id:133}
  ],
  links: [
  {source:1, target:11},
  {source:1, target:12},
  {source:1, target:13},
  {source:11, target:111},
  {source:11, target:112},
  {source:11, target:113},
  {source:12, target:121},
  {source:12, target:122},
  {source:12, target:123},
  {source:13, target:131},
  {source:13, target:132},
  {source:13, target:133},
  ]
};


var svg = d3.select("svg");

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(d => d.id))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-5000))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(750, 750));

var link = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("stroke", 'red')


var node = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", d => d.shape || rect)
      .attr("height", "50")
      .attr("fill", d => d.color || "wheat")
      .attr("stroke", 'black')
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

  simulation.nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

function ticked() {
  link.attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
      .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
      .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
      .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);

  node.attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`)
}

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) 
    simulation.alphaTarget(1).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) 
    simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

function rnd(base){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * base);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg viewbox="0 0 1500 1500" height="100vh"></svg>
```

PS: что делать со связями нужно подумать, я полагаю нужно создать невидимых узлов и группировать их, как в примере по ссылке в комментарии

Comment: О, круто! Можно граф за вершинки подёргать)))

Comment: @Qwertiy да, это прикольный layout, я похожее уже постил, ссылка есть в комментах к вопросу =)

Comment: спасибо за пример, но буду разбираться в библиотеке, чтобы реализовать нужный функционал

Comment: @АлександрНикитин спрашивайте еще что-то надо будет

Comment: Смотрю и думаю, а где такое применяется))?

Comment: @spoon100500 в визуализации данных)

Comment: Ну понятно, что перетаскивание кружков это визуализация, а данные тут где? и зачем их таскать за кружки)))

Comment: @spoon100500 конкретно этот пример - просто пример =)